# WPF set window background from image resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window

I am trying to set the window background from an image in my "Resources" folder:

```
<Window Background="{StaticResource MyImageBrush}">
<Window.Resources>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="MyImageBrush" ImageSource="/ApplicationName;component/Data/
        MyImage.jpg" />
</Window.Resources>
```

It compiles correctly but then a message error appear when Visual Studio refreshes the xaml view after compiling saying:

> StaticResource reference 'MyImageBrush' was not found.

If I remove background attribute for window, then I compile, and it compiles ok, then I put the background attribute again and it works, but then when compiling again is shown the above message error.

How could I set the window background from xaml if possible?

Comment: When you say "Resources" folder, that should be part of the [Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf), e.g. `ImageSource="/Resources/Data/MyImage.jpg"`. That said, you can't reference a resource from `Window.Resources` in the outer `<Window>` tag. Move the resource to `Application.Resources` in App.xaml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to declare a resource. Assign the Window's Background property directly:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Data/MyImage.jpg"/>
    </Window.Background>
    ...
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you can move `ImageBrush` resource to `App.xaml`